# How to make a data.frame with 1 row 0 column?

Tags: r

```
R> data.frame()
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

I can make the above data.frame with 0 row and 0 column. How to make a data.frame with 1 row and 0 column?

EDIT: It is absolutely useful, as shown in the following use case.

```
R> data.frame(data.frame(), y=1)
Error in data.frame(data.frame(), y = 1) :
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
R> data.frame(data.frame(x=1)[,0,drop=F], y=1)
  y
1 1
```

Comment: You can't have a row without a column I'm afraid. data.frames in R are a list of column vectors. "rows" are just slides across those column vectors. Why are you trying to create such an object?

Comment: I have upvoted this question because it's about an object that shouldn't be deliberately created, like @MrFlick says.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by making a one by one data.frame and selecting the first zero columns:

```
data.frame(x=1)[,0,drop=FALSE]
#data frame with 0 columns and 1 row
```

Check that this does have the right dimensions:

```
dim(data.frame(x=1)[,0,drop=FALSE])
#[1] 1 0
```

Comment: Interesting. But note the result does no longer function as a usual dataframe. E.g. `rbind(data.frame(x=1)[,0,drop=FALSE], data.frame(x=1)[,0,drop=FALSE])` gives a dataframe with 0 rows instead of two rows as you would expect. I think this is because your structure has one rowonly because of the `row.names` attribute and not because of content.

Comment: I think that it is just a bug in R.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution.

```
nrow=1 # this can be tuned to return n rows 0 column data.frame.
structure(data.frame(), row.names = seq(nrow))
```